# crystal report asks for password in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports

i would like to not be asked for entering username & password when i implement print task i will be asked for input database password .

and all of my code to Load crystal report is :

```
      crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
      crystalReportViewer1.PrintReport();
      this.Close();
```

Note : my login have sql server authentication not windows authentication

Comment: All i knew is Crystal Report sometimes need to login into DB.

Answer (score 0):

you have to install run time app. i think its name is "CRedist" 
and if your client OS is 64 bit version you have to install both x86 and x64 versions.